# How to visualize tf.compat.v1 static graph in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow

For a given graph, how can we visualize the graph using tensorboard for tf.compat.v1 ?
Sharing this here after searching everywhere. Most of the documentations explains tf.keras and not for tf.compat.v1 static graphs

Answer (score 0):

First export the graph to a logdir that tensorboard can use!

```py
import tensorflow as tf

# Get the default graph
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter("logs", graph)
```

After that simply open tensorboard in the specified directory (here `logs/`)

`python -m tensorboard.main --logdir logs/`